# Intermittent login issue with ASP.Net MVC Project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am having an odd issue with an ASP.NET MVC project when logging in. It doesn't happen for the majority of users and in our dev team it doesn't happen to two people but does for the others.

When logging in, i.e. entering username/password and hitting enter, the response posts correctly and the last line of code hit is: `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");`.

But then the loading icon just keeps spinning and never stops, staying on the login page. If I go to the URL at the top and change the address to the default it loads ok meaning the authentication was successful but never seemed to move onto the page. If you log off and try again it does not occur and seems to be the case if you clear the cache.

Its very hard to test as it isn't consistent and no errors appear in Event Viewer, Visual Studio, Browser dev tools, Fiddler, Stackify, Glimpse or anything else I have tried to debug it with. I can see from the end response of the post that it ends in "Object moved to here" i.e. redirects - status code 302.

Does anyone know of any issue like this or can point to a way I can debug this?

EDIT/UPDATE: It appears to happen on one machine if the entire browser is closed and re-opened before debugging or not used the application for a period of time. That does possibly suggest something session related to me but still not sure what it could be.

EDIT - Last item on Stackify Prefix for Login Post request:

```
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-StackifyID: V1|af9582c3-5686-4cda-b02b-5ebd3543a07d|
x-frame-options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
Cache-Control: private
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Location: /
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Set-Cookie: .CookieNameRemoved=E99D5A4CCB34300380B44516C2685DFF59781B20CCB8B71BD2F75586D94C7E6FEB37574B884E350BE605C6F27CAE4333522670E9092D054E70E35C0DE3314CC66A55DCDE948864EEE8EB1199AE40A4BB141A3B88AE92EE86B651EDEC26CD72B3B7F50B858B64D5FD41EF364577767AD836B75E69D700BE2DC1F491CF77ACAC7405157DD20CDDE95F02423F21E597F5731D918633627FDFDC3E552C2FC71F42A57D7812AA433AE7810DAE5AB66BAEAE72EA394BA3DE8FE110F197FF5D9B2B1E6A8BB42D9BD7B599B1C940BA8A7CBC0D4802F774A897B310E42DB82B2F164B300BC03C9B199E365CA12A26255FFA2EBBBAB6BF31EC; path=/,SiteNumber=1; expires=Wed, 04-Mar-2020 16:06:36 GMT; path=/
Stackify-Length: 118

Response:
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

But last dev tool check on Chrome shows post request at status of pending.

Comment: Do you have logging in your application. I suggest to have information logged in each step of operations in the code and check them when the issue occurs. It will help you to figure out the coz of the issue.

Comment: Do you have any asynchronous calls/code in your login action? Could be that an exception is being thrown (and lost) that causes the action to hang.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I've used the internal Visual Studio logging, stackify prefix and more but no error appears. Do you have a specific log type you think I should check?

Comment: @phuzi No async calls no just the typical HttpGet for the view and the HttpPost for authentication and redirect. I have a feeling either an exception is thrown or its got into a redirect loop somehow but can't get any errors out

Comment: Once the browser hangs, have you tried opening up your browser's dev tools to see what response you get from the server, and see if you get any JavaScript errors? You say you get a 302 - if that were the case, your browser should redirect you. If it's not, then you've got some sort of client side error.

Comment: @mason yes, tried with Firefox, Chrome and Edge (before Chromium) tools. No errors of any kind, network shows ok and yes its a 302 and in almost every case it does redirect to the correct page but its just these random times it will sit there and NEVER timeout

Comment: When it fails, what does the browser's network tools say about the 302? Does it attempt to then make a new request to the location specified by the 302?

Comment: The last network item log shows the post, status of 302 and response text of a page with Object moved to here. I'm going to try and get the error again now to confirm

Comment: I've added stackify prefix detail above, chrome dev tool shows request at pending indefinitely at the moment

Comment: The .map file issue is probably not related.

Comment: Correct I still have issue, wishful thinking!

Answer (score 0):

I changed the Login.cshtml to use Ajax.BeginForm instead and did a manual redirection simply using window.location.href and so far I no longer have the issue.  This leaves me to believe that the issue is likely some form of redirect loop but I can't be certain.

I still have a branch with the previous form type for testing if anyone has any further suggestions for trying to debug the issue.